# Add a drawing to the worksheet with PHPExcel

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

This is the first time I try to add a logo/picture to the worksheet with PHPExcel but I'm getting following error:

Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'File localhost/MTSuperadmin/template/images/Logo Mie Titi .png not found!' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MTSuperadmin\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Worksheet\Drawing.php:114.

I had checking it and I'm sure that there is file png named "Logo Mie Titi .png" in MTSuperadmin/template/images.

This is my code:

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Logo');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
$logo = base_url() . 'template/images/Logo Mie Titi .png';
$objDrawing->setPath($logo);
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(8);
$objDrawing->setOffsetY(300);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setHeight(75); 
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

Thanks for your answer.... :)

Comment: Filesystem root !== web root..... Your need to use a filesystem file reference when adding an image.

Comment: how I do that?
Can you give me an example code?

Comment: Change `$logo = base_url() . 'template/images/Logo Mie Titi .png';
` to use the actual __filesystem__ path to your image file

Comment: I'd checking it and the file is there.

Comment: What's the value of `base_url()`? Is it a filesystem reference? or is it a `url`?

Comment: it's a url. 
localhost/MTSuperadmin/template/images/Logo Mie Titi .png
base_url = localhost/MTSuperadmin.

Comment: You can't use a URL.... when embedding an image in an Excel worksheet, PHPExcel needs to be able to stat the file, and PHP's url wrapper doesn't support that for urls.... so the file needs to be within the server's filesystem

Comment: If the file is on your localhost as that url suggests, then give PHPExcel the filesystem reference to the file, not the URL

Comment: Thank you Mr. Mark Baker. I will try .... :)